# Getting a single object from SQL Server to a view

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a an object of type `Picture` that contains a List Comments see source code here http://pastebin.me/21148a93065bddb7302e160f5a0ac1fb

I then want to take an `Picture.ID` and show the image that has that unique ID from my database

So I made a ActionResult Comment in my GalleryController http://pastebin.me/21148a93065bddb7302e160f5a0acb02 with a HttpGet

I then have this view that should display the requested image and the comments in its list http://pastebin.me/21148a93065bddb7302e160f5a0acb02

But I am not sure if its the List that is not initialized or if I am just doing it wrong but I get an error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>   Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Source error: http://pastebin.me/21148a93065bddb7302e160f5a0ad965

Comment: You should try to post the **relevant** bits of source in your post directly - cross-linking to a separate site is a bit messy and requires lots of clicks from your readers.....

Comment: Yes but marking the code as code often still looks very wrong, especially if its partially/fully html code

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I cant get it to only parse a single object (And I know there will always be max one result as it searches in the database on the primary key)

So my code is now

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Comment(string ID)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        if (ID != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var model = from r in _db.Gallery
                            where r.ID == id
                            select r;

                return View(model);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And

```
    @model IEnumerable<firstweb4.Models.Picture>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Comment";
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <a href="@item.Path"><img src="@item.Path" alt="@item.Title" width="250px"  /> </a>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Posted by
            </th>
            <th>
                Comment
            </th>
            <th>
                Posted on
            </th>
        </tr>    
    @foreach (var comment in item.PictureComments)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @comment.Auther
            </td>
            <td>
                @comment.Text
            </td>
            <td>
                @comment.PostedTime
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
    }
}
```

So I itterate through a the singleitem collection I parse and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine the Action method in question.  First of all, I see this and this should almost never exist:

```
            catch
            {
            }
```

So if an exception was thrown, you're just swallowing it up and will never know about it.  This would result in returning a view with no model passed in, thus the model referenced in your strongly-typed view is null.  This seems like a very good possibility of what's happening.

Also, why do you keep overwriting `ViewBag.Picture` inside your `foreach` loop?  Is that really what you intended to do?

Hopefully this will get you on the right path and you'll quickly get to the underlying issue.